# How to get categorychildren in a list under topcategories (magento)

Tags: php, loops, magento, magento-1.9

I want a list of categories with under each categoryname their children categories. But my code isn't working, the top categories are showing but

```
<ul class="sub"></ul>
```

is empty, so the children are not showing.

This is my code:

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addFieldToFilter('level',2)
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('url');
$out = "<ul>";
foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
    $children = $cat->getChildren();
    $out .= "<li>";
    $out .= "<b><a href='".$cat->getUrl()."'>".$cat->getName()."</a></b>";
        $out .="<ul class='sub'>";
        foreach($children as $child){
            $ChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
            $out .="<li><a href='".$ChildModel->getUrl()."'>".$ChildModel->getName()."</a></li>";
        }
        $out .="</ul>";
    $out .= "</li>";
}
$out .= "</ul>";
echo $out;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It could be that your only grabbing the level 2 categories.

Comment: try var_dump $children inside the first loop.

Comment: var_dump($children)

Answer (score 0):

since you are using filtered collection i suppose you will have to load items to get children

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId())->getChildrenCategories();
```

Comment: your other code may also fail 

1. On using addAttributeToSelect on a category model. Since it is a collection method. 

2. On using load() method with object instead of id
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child)